# How to create dynamic form in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

This is a very simple thing to do with controls in asp.net, but I have no idea how to accomplish it in MVC.  I have a page where I want the user to type in his employee id.  If the employeeid is in the database, I want to remove the log in and show a survey for them to fill out.  If the employeeid is not in the database, I want to show them a form to collect their employee information.  After they submit their information, I want to show them the survey.

They can fill out several surveys, so I would like to have the survey submit to the same page with the option of creating a new survey or editing one they have previously done.  Any time they come to this page and type in their employee id, I want to show them a list of their previous surveys with the option to create a new one.

How can I accomplish this in MVC?  Do I create a view and use partials for the survey and log in form?  I'm not sure how MVC best handles this sort of scenario.

Comment: Have you tried either? There are any number of ways to accomplish these things depending on how you want the UI to work. You can use partials, redirect to new pages, UI design is really no different in MVC than in WebForms. Work on it a bit and come back with a specific question.

Comment: I tried a view with a partial (simple textbox that takes the employeeid.)  When the user hits submit, the form calls the action and checks the db.  But it returns the partial again with the employeeid textbox.  I want this to disappear.  In addition, I want to show another partial? with the survey.  I'm afraid that there is a good way to accomplish this with MVC but I am trying to apply asp.net techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change what is shown in the view easily based on the supplied ViewMdel (or ViewBag if you use that). For example something like:

```
@if (Model.HasEmployeeID)
{
    <form>
        <!-- your form here -->
    </form>
}
else
{
    <div class="survey">
        <!-- your survey here -->
    </div>
}
```

For something that you are only going to use once, you can just leave it all in one view. For something that will be reusable (or if you just like that level of organization) you could make the form and/or survey a partial view.

Based on your description I would expect the survey at least to be well suited for a partial view.

Comment: Do you suggest putting a bool HasEmployeeID in the model or do something like this:  if(Model.EmployeeID != "") ... then show form?

Comment: This ultimately helped me construct a solution, although I used if(Model == null) as my test.

Comment: I generally prefer an bool value over a null check because the intent is very explicit. A value being null affecting flow logic isn't as intuitive in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend that you research a little bit on the MVC pattern for web applications
and start here...
http://www.asp.net/mvc

For the login scenario check these post out
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049(v=vs.100).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

I would general have a structure like this

http://myapp.com/surveys/  Actions-> (all, single create, single update, single delete)

http://myapp.com/trainings Actions ->(all, single create, single update, single delete)

http://myapp.com/users/ Actions-> (create, update, delete)

Surveys are the surveys with the actions... Trainings are the filled out surveys aligned to the users... and users are the users...

This could be a simple run down of how to structure the mvc routs for the first shot... devil is in the details =)... like always ...
But this should give u enough food to start...

HTH